# replacing characters in a CLOB column (db2)

Tags: db2, clob

I have a `CLOB(2000000)` field in a db2 (v10) database, and I would like to run a simple `UPDATE` query on it to replace each occurances of "foo" to "baaz".

Since the contents of the field is more then 32k, I get the following error:

```
"{some char data from field}" is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001
```

How can I replace the values?

**UPDATE**:
The query was the following (changed UPDATE into SELECT for easier testing):

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_clob_column, 'foo', 'baaz') FROM my_table WHERE id = 10726
```

**UPDATE 2**
As mustaccio pointed out, `REPLACE` does not work on `CLOB` fields (or at least not without doing a cast to `VARCHAR` on the data entered - which in my case is not possible since the size of the data is more than 32k) - the question is about finding an alternative way to acchive the `REPLACE` functionallity for `CLOB` fields.

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: You may want to show the actual statement that you ran. Also, is this DB2 for z/OS? (It's the only platform that has version 10.)

Comment: Updated my question with the query

Comment: The function `REPLACE` accepts and returns `VARCHAR`, so you obviously cannot use it to work with `CLOB` columns.

Comment: Have you tried the db2 built-in modules?

Comment: I have tried dbms_lob; it contains a lot usefull methods, but it doesnt have REPLACE. Also, SYSFUN.REPLACE has the same limitations (32k)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, since I have found no way to this by an SQL query, I ended up exporting the table, editing its lob content in Notepad++, and importing the table back again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your case: There are 2 different REPLACE functions offered by DB2, [SYSIBM.REPLACE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000843.html) and [SYSFUN.REPLACE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0060262.html). The version of REPLACE in SYSFUN accepts CLOBs and supports values up to 1 MByte. In case your values are longer than you would need to write your own (SQL-based?) function.

BTW: You can check function resolution by executing "values(current path)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My fields are sadly larger than 1Mb (around 3-4Mb)